# Unix Shell file transfer

Tags: file, unix, scp, transfer

I just started using Unix and I need to copy of few files from my class folder to my MAC.

Files are `lab1.txt` and `lab1script`, unix host is `myname@stdlinux.myschool` and directory is `/home/1/name/c4251/bin`

I need it to go to my desktop or somewhere I can find it at least, I've been using scp with the syntax:

```
scp lab1.txt myname@stdlinux.myschool:lab1.txt
```

I really can't figure out what is going on any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your mac and open the terminal. The format is:

```
scp from to
```

So you are going to type:

```
scp myname@stdlinux.myschool:~/home/1/name/c4251/bin/* .
```

you are copying everything in the bin folder (by using the `*`) to your current folder (from which you are making this call) which is denoted by `.`

Comment: It says /home/1/name/home/1/name/c4251/bin/* no such file or directory found.  I've tried calling it from the terminal running the shell and from my MAC's default terminal.

Comment: running sftp and calling the directory got it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `/home/1/name/home/1/name/c4251/bin/*`   --- you have `/home/1/` twice...is this intentional??

Comment: Yeah, that is the error it gave me.  Not sure what was going on, but making a call from the mac terminal using sftp let me download the files to my home computer.

Answer (score 0):

user2371502 almost had it:

```
scp myname@stdlinux.myschool:/home/1/name/c4251/bin/* ~/Desktop/
```